# How to prevent photoresistor sensor from draining battery

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, low-power, attiny, photoresistor

I'm looking for a simple hack to minimise current when detecting change in light intensity using photoresistor.
I'm using ATTiny85 in deep sleep (power down, ADC disabled, using below 1 microamp) waking by pin change (interrupt pin). After pin change ATTiny executes some operations and goes to sleep again. Device is powered with small battery and the battery should last for a year.

The event that wakes microcontroller is change on pin PB3. PB3 is connected to ground by photoresistor.
Everything works as expected. Change in light conditions wakes the microcontroller, and after some actions it goes to sleep again.

The photoresistor, when it is dark, has 1 megohm resistance, so the current is minimal. But when it is sunny, the resistance falls below 10 kilohm, and the PB3 pin leaks above 50 microamps all day, even though the microcontroller is in deep sleep, not doing anything. I'm interested only in pin change, so after it gets sunny, and the low photoresistor resistance triggers PB3 I'd like somehow to block the current flow till the next change.

Is there any simple circuit (possible using capacitor?) to achieve that?

Comment: how is the LDR draining the battery? ... what is the circuit?

Comment: Consider using a photodiode/small solar cell to *generate* a current for the signal instead of using a resistor to shunt it to ground.

Comment: +1 @vir, even a LED can be used as "solar cell"

Comment: @vir your comment deserves an update to an answer. It has many interesting possibilities, for example photocell can be wired to power the circuit when it is sunny to extend battery life. If combined with supercap it may even take over entirely, turning battery into a mere backup.

Comment: @Maple I agree but I am currently just on my phone and also unfortunately supercap backup is not my forte. I'm sure someone else on here is though!

Comment: @vir how to connect photodiode/small cell to trigger pin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sleep on the watchdog timer (or other low power timer) instead and then only power the photodetector at the end of each sleep.

Connect the top of the photoresistor circuit to a GPIO so that you can power the circuit off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZllkq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using periodic waking up each second with watchdog timer could be in fact simpler. I could store previous reading in memory (as I undrestand the variables in memory are retained even during deep sleep) and detect change. What is the correct wiring of input pin to photoresistor for maximum current saving? Right now I have pin connected by phototransistor to GND - is this correct way?

Comment: GPIO2 in this diagram is digital input right?

Comment: yes, indeed it is.